# Using a Swift completion block with a nullable String value in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a Swift function who's signature is the following:

`func detectLanguage(forString string: String, completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void)`

In certain cases it returns a String, other cases it returns nil.

When I get autocompleted in my obj-c files, this is what I get:

```
[translator detectLanguageForString:@"foo" completion:^(NSString * _Nonnull) {
    // some code
}];
```

If I change the block slightly:

`[translator detectLanguageForString:@"foo" completion:^(NSString *lang _Nullable) {`

Xcode throws a very vague error:

> Expected ')'

How can I properly get this completion block working safely? Thanks.

Comment: Martin R's answer gives the correct syntax. If you want us to try to figure out why you're getting the wrong autocomplete, you'll need to show the full declaration of `detectLanguage`, tell us what version of Xcode you're using, and tell us what your Swift language version is set to.

Comment: It was set to 3.3, updated to 4.1 to see if that fixes things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Objective-C block needs a parameter, and that comes after the type 
`NSString * _Nullable`:

```
[translator detectLanguageForString:@"foo" completion:^(NSString * _Nullable lang) {
    // ...
}];
```

Comment: Ahh, it was the order of things. Thanks!